# Error while creating index in SQL Azure

Tags: index, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create an index on table `[Children]` in SQL Azure but get the following error:

> The operation failed because an index or statistics with name
>   'IX_Children_ParentID' already exists on table 'Children'.

As far as I can see there's no index or statistics with this name. The following command returned zero results so there shouldn't be any indexes or statistics. Is that correct?

```
SELECT object_id, name FROM sys.stats WHERE name = 'IX_Children_ParentID'
UNION ALL
SELECT object_id, name FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'IX_Children_ParentID'
```

**UPDATE:** Changed the query in response to @Shark's anwer.

My SQL command for creating the index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Children_ParentID
ON [myschema].[Children]
(
    [ParentID] DESC
)
```

Before this error occurred I had problems with timeouts while creating the index. Could this be caused by some remnants?

Comment: What is the DDL for the Children table? What is the PK defined as?

Answer (score 1):

The catalog view `sys.all_objects` won't show nonclustered indexes.  Here's the query you should be using:

```
select
    object_name(object_id) as table_name, 
    name as index_name
from sys.indexes
where name = 'IX_Children_ParentID'
```

Or to get all of the indexes for that table:

```
select
    object_name(object_id) as table_name, 
    name as index_name
from sys.indexes
where object_name(object_id) = 'Children'
```

Comment: Thanks. Still there's no indexes in the result (I've queried sys.stats as well). The SQL Server Management Studio isn't showing any index or statistics in the GUI either.

Comment: Check for unique constraints or PK's named like that (IX_Children_ParentID).

Comment: @Marian, yes of course. I posted this question just because I can't find the cause of it.

Comment: @JonasStensved What was the result set of my second query that retrieves all indexes for that table?

Comment: @Shark, just the primary key; [PK_Children]

Comment: @JonasStensved Does this table have data in it?